# Unable to read a cookie from perl when set by a php webpage

Tags: php, perl, cookies

I have 2 webpages under the same host. 1 in php and 1 in perl cgi.

The php page is setting a cookie "c" under a domain "d.com" and path "/".

In perl I am trying to read the value of the cookie "c".

I tried the following code :

```
use CGI;    
use CGI::Cookie;

my $query = new CGI;
print $query->header();
#... some more code ...
$thecookie = $query->cookie(-name=>'c', -domain=>"d.com", -path=>"/");
print $thecookie;
```

Any help/idea would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show the incoming HTTP request headers that contain the cookie? The easiest way to get them is through your brower's developer tools.

Comment: Actually as stated below I found the issue. The problem is that the cookie was set to "secure" which force the browser to send the cookie only over https. Since the perl page was accessed via http, the browser was not returning the cookie. Simple as that.

Comment: Ha, didn't read all the comments. You should write your own answer. ;)

Comment: Done, I posted my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that had this issue. **The solution was simple**.

The problem is that the cookie was set to **"secure"** which force the browser to send the cookie only over **https**.

Since the perl page was accessed via **http**, the browser was not returning the cookie. Simple as that.

Accessing the page via **https** fixed the issue.